# Как найти ближайшее общее значение из двух датафреймов?

Tags: pandas, циклы, dataframe, for

У меня есть два датафрейма, они не совпадают по количеству строк, нужно взять значения со второго датафрейма, которые будут приблизительно совпадать со значениями первого

> [image: первый датафрейм]
>
> [image: Второй датафрейм]

Как я пытался это решить эту задачу, я хотел создать цикл, в котором каждое значение с первого датафрейма отнималось со значений второго датафрейма, потом ввести значения с минимальной разницей в новый датафрейм. Вопрос состоит в том, что как произвести такой расчет?
Вот пример кода

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('dataGISFZI.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)
df1 = pd.read_excel('dataGISFZI.xlsx', sheet_name = 1)

a = list(df['Mdcore'])
b = list(df1['MD'])

for i in a:
    MDcore = a[i]
    for j in df1:
        MD = b[i]
        absolute_difference_function = lambda list_value : abs(MDcore[i] - MD[i])

        closest_value = min(MD, key=absolute_difference_function)

print(closest_value)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Буду весьма признателен за ответ.

Comment: pandas.merge_asof() ?

Comment: Приведите пример, что вы хотите получить на выходе, а то не очень понятно.

Comment: А так то вы перебираете *значения* из колонки, а используете их как *индексы*, подумайте внимательнее, что вы делаете.

Comment: @CrazyElf я на выходе должен получить значения со второго датафрейма, которые максимально схожи со значениями первого датафрейма.

Comment: @SandalIvanov Ага, ну вам же уже подсказали - смотрите на метод https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: спасибо, это то что мне нужно